# Importar datos con array en django a mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Mi duda es, como puedo importar estos datos con este código?
Lo ejecuto desde un test.py

```
from core.erp.models import Categorias

data = ['Botas', 'Botines', 'Mocasines', 'Sandalias', 'Tenis']

for i in data:
    cat = Categorias(nombre=i)
    cat.save()
    print('Guardado registro No {}'.format(cat.id))
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Se supone que si tengo importada mi app en settings
Espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Si usas pytest**

```py
    # -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
    [pytest]
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = test_settings
    # -- recommended but optional:
    python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

**2. Escribe esto en tu terminal**

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```